# Log on cibc investors edge automatically with VBA

Tags: vba

Hello I am writing code to automatically log onto CIBC investors edge and my code only opens of the cibc investors page. I have a feeling it is a problem with how I am calling the username and password values. Below is the general code and the element snapshots from the inspected elements on CIBC.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub MyInvEdge()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "https://www.investorsedge.cibc.com/ie/"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
Myrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.userID.Value = "my ID"
HTMLDoc.all.userPassword.Value = "my password"
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "Sign On" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

The HTML code for both elements is the following:

```
<input name="userID" tabindex="3" id="userID" onkeydown="keyPressedEvt
(event,'newUserID');" type="text" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off">

<input name="userPassword" tabindex="4" id="userPassword" type="password"
 maxlength="12" autocomplete="off">
```

Please help me sort out this sign in issue.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
HTMLDoc.all.userID.Value = "my ID"
```

should be something like

```
HTMLDoc.GetElementByID("userID").Value ="my ID"
```

(same for password)

---

Also, use `DoEvents` to pass control back to the processor when waiting for the page to load:

So something like

```
While MyBrowser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
```

instead of

```
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

---

Finally, I'm not sure "Sign On" is a HTML element, so using `.Type` won't work here:

```
MyHTML_Element.Type = "Sign On"
```

But you haven't shown the HTML for that...